# Realm accessed from incorrect thread using async and await

Tags: swift, async-await, realm

Running the code below i get "Realm accessed from incorrect thread." error on the second `try! realm.write({` line ,  the first write line causes no error. Any idea on how to fix it?

```
let realm = try! await Realm()
                        print("User Realm User file location: \(realm.configuration.fileURL!.path)")
                        try! realm.write { // <= No error here
                            realm.add(groups, update: .modified)
                        }
                        StartApp._Groups = groups
                        if let items  = await api.getArticles(aricleIDs: ids) {
                            try! realm.write({ // <= Error here
                                realm.add(items, update: .modified)
                            })
                            StartApp._Items = items
                            var index = 0
                            StartApp._Items = StartApp.Items.map { item in
                                item.i = index
                                index = index + 1
                                return item
                            }
                            groups.forEach { group in
                                group.items = items.filter({ $0.groupId == group.id })
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: try? realm.write({ 
                                realm.add(items, update: .modified)
                            })
Try Like This

Comment: Why are you doing this `await Realm()` in the first place? Generally the await is for a query or read to be able to asynchronously handle the data see [Async/Await Query MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/swift/examples/mongodb-remote-access/#async-await-query-mongodb). It really replaced the `function.async` method calls. Oh, and the closure following this `await api.getArticles` is a different thread - remember is asynchronous and is running independently.

Comment: @Jay The default constructor uses await in the version i am using

Comment: @Jay the second closure you mean the second `realm.write` ?

Comment: i change to this: `let realm = try! Realm(queue: .main)` then i get an NSError

Comment: Again, you don't need to do any of that. `let realm = try! Realm` is sufficient. If you're using Realm sync, it's different. The async calls are generally on the Realm functions as it can take time to retreive data, the initial local Realm var doesn't need that. Are you seeing something different in the [Realm Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/swift/quick-start/#open-a-realm)?

Comment: i downgraded realm and used non `try! await Realm()` and also consolidated the writes into one, now works

Comment: Can you add what you did to correct the issue as an answer? It may be helpful to future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i fixed with the below , removed the await Realm() and consolidated writes into one

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{
                        do {
                            let realm = try Realm()
           
                            var index = 0
                            items.forEach { item in
                                item.i = index
                                index = index + 1
                            }
                            try realm.write({
                                realm.add(groups, update: .modified)
                                realm.add(items, update: .modified)
                               }
                            })
                        } catch {
                            print("Realm error: \(error)")
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is using `await` when initializing Realm, which is basically saying instantiate realm on some OTHER async context and come back. Even if it was possible there is no need. Realm initializer is not async.

The requirement is for realm to complete the transaction on the same async context (thread) it was instantiated.
This could be insured with async await by wrapping the instantiation and transaction in a block of code with the the `withCheckedContinuation` function (there's also a throwing one `withCheckedThrowingContinuation`). Read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/withcheckedcontinuation(function:_:)) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/withcheckedthrowingcontinuation(function:_:))

Here's how it would look:

```
    public func loadSomething(with id: String) async throws -> Something {
        let result = try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            do {
                let realm = try Realm()
                guard let something = realm.object(ofType: DBSomething.self, forPrimaryKey: id) else {
                    throw YourError.somethingHappened
                }
                continuation.resume(with: something)
            } catch {
                continuation.resume(with: .failure(error))
            }
        }
        return result
    }
```